# Missing reference setting up Web API with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, appfabric

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api) for building with ASP.NET Web API and MVC 3, but am running into a problem around Step 4 tring to add this line:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api/contacts", new HttpServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ContactsApi)));
```

The issue seems to be around the `HttpServiceHostFactory`; I don't have the proper reference. The related namespace is `Microsoft.ApplicationServer`, which I cannot find on my machine at all. I've installed AppFabric to no avail. Any idea where I can find this, and why it wasn't installed along with Web API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh. Found the answer - grabbed the wrong NuGet package. When searching through the packages, "WebApi.All" never showed, both other webApi packages did. Had more success using the Package Manager Console and typing in `Install-Package WebApi.All -Version 0.6.0`.
Soooo... nevermind.